# Why does Plex Media Server's PID keep increasing in "top"?

Tags: linux, media, server, plex

I've searched first to no avail. When I type:

```
sudo service plexmediaserver start
```

and then:

```
top
```

I get:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2908 plex      15  -5  149896  17964   9436 D   2.6  0.5   0:00.05 Plex Media+
```

Then if I run top again I get:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2912 plex      15  -5  149896  17964   9436 D   2.6  0.5   0:00.05 Plex Media+
```

and so on. If I continue refreshing `top` the PID of Plexmediaserver keeps increasing. Plex is no longer accessible via a web browser or DLNA enabled device.

I have tried to remove and reinstall with

```
sudo apt-get remove plexmediaserver
sudo dpkg -i plex*.deb
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
-Nick

Comment: It's crashing on startup, and something is restarting it, but it doesn't run for more than a few seconds. Try to find a log file to find out why it's crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I looked at the error logs and found some reference to sqlite3, googled that, and found a solution over at the plex forums.

```
mv /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Plug-in Support/Databases/* ./plexscrewedup
sudo service plexmediaserver stop
sudo service plexmediaserver start
```

Done! You have to re-add all of your libraries but at least the server is back up and running.